# Tamaño de visualizacion de pagina

Tags: css, html5, css3, tailwind

¡Hola,Espero que estén muy bien!

Quería comprobar si podían echar un vistazo a algún problema que tengo con esta pagina.

Al abrir este sitio web mediante Deploy en Github o Netilify, aparece la página con un zoom más alto, como si estuviera por encima del 100%.

cuando lo abro en liveserver desde vscode o directamente a través de un archivo HTML, abre con el tamaño de contenido correcto, agregué la base del tamaño de fuente a la configuración tailwind 16px o 100% y lo hizo funcionar al abrir a través de un archivo HTML, pero aún no trabajando en cuando implemento el documento

Doc

https://github.com/Ramses1406/Chat-app-Ram.git

live site https://incandescent-jelly-e743c6.netlify.app/

https://ramses1406.github.io/Chat-app-Ram/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat-App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/output.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body
    class="lg:items-center lg:flex lg:flex-row lg:bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet lg:gap-[8rem]"
  >
    <!--FORMA_BG-->

    <div class="">
      <div
        class="w-[13rem] rounded-br-full lg:rounded-b-full lg:h-[55rem] lg:w-[35rem] h-[40rem] bg-gradient-to-t from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] absolute"
      ></div>

      <main class="px-10 py-20 lg:ml-[31rem] bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet">
        <!-- main cel -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
          <!-- CEL MAIN BG -->
          <div class="z-10 p-3 py-5 bg-white rounded-3xl">
            <!-- header PURPLE -->
            <div
              class="flex items-center justify-between bg-gradient-to-r rounded-b-md rounded-t-2xl from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] px-6 py-8 relative"
            >
              <div
                class="absolute w-[10rem] h-[2rem] bg-white left-[7.3rem] bottom-[5rem] rounded-b-3xl"
              ></div>

              <div class="flex items-center justify-start gap-2">
                <i class="text-white fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>

                <div>
                  <img
                    src="./images/avatar.jpg"
                    class="h-10 rounded-full border-[2px] white border-"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <h1 class="text-lg text-white">Samuel Green</h1>
                  <p class="text-xs text-white/40">Available to Walk</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <i class="text-white fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- BG- INSIDE CEL -->
            <div
              class="px-4 pt-5 pb-4 rounded-b-2xl bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet"
            >
              <!-- CHAT -->
              <section>
                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] text-sm bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  That sounds great. <br />
                  I’d be happy with that.
                </p>

                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  Could you send over some <br />
                  pictures of your dog, please?
                </p>

                <!-- RESPUESTAS -->
                <div class="flex justify-end gap-3 item-self">
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-1.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-2.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <img
                    src="/images/dog-image-3.jpg"
                    class="h-12 rounded-lg"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col items-end">
                  <p class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-lg w-fit">
                    Here are a few pictures. She’s a happy girl!
                  </p>
                  <p class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm bg-white rounded-lg w-fit">
                    Can you make it?
                  </p>
                </div>

                <p
                  class="px-3 py-2 mb-2 text-sm rounded-lg text-[#9e38a9] bg-primary-GrayishBlue/40 w-fit"
                >
                  She looks so happy! The time <br />
                  we discussed works. How <br />
                  long shall I take her out for?
                </p>
              </section>

              <div
                class="flex justify-between gap-2 py-5 rounded-lg rounded-bl-none px-14 bg-gradient-to-l from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] max-w-[17rem] mb-2"
              >
                <p class="text-sm text-white/60">30 minute walk</p>
                <span class="text-lg font-bold text-white"> $29 </span>
              </div>

              <div
                class="flex justify-between gap-2 py-5 rounded-lg rounded-bl-none px-14 bg-gradient-to-l from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] max-w-[17rem]"
              >
                <p class="text-sm text-white/60">1 hour walk</p>
                <span class="text-lg font-bold text-white"> $49 </span>
              </div>

              <!-- TYPING BAR -->

              <div
                class="relative flex items-center justify-between px-20 py-3 mx-auto mt-2 bg-white rounded-3xl"
              >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message..." />

                <i
                  class="absolute fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right right-[0.6rem] opacity-80 text-4xl"
                ></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <div
      class="px-10 pt-12 pb-20 lg:min-w-[50rem] bg-Secondary-LightGrayishViolet"
    >
      <h1 class="text-6xl font-bold text-center lg:text-start">
        Simple booking
      </h1>

      <p
        class="pt-4 text-lg font-medium leading-[1.9rem] lg:text-start text-center text-gray-400 lg:hidden"
      >
        Stay in touch with our dog walkers <br />
        through the chat interface. This makes it <br />
        easy to discuss arrangements and make <br />
        bookings. Once the walk has been <br />
        completed you can rate your walker and <br />
        book again all through the chat.
      </p>

      <pre class="text-lg text-gray-400 text-start max-lg:hidden">

Stay in touch with our dog walkers  through the chat
interface. This makes it   easy to discuss arrangements and 
make bookings.Once the walk has been completed you can
rate your walker and  book again all through the chat.
        </pre
      >
    </div>

    <!-- BG-FORM #2 -->
    <div
      class="w-[13rem] max-lg:hidden opacity-5 lg:rounded-t-full lg:h-[55rem] lg:w-[35rem] h-[40rem] bg-gradient-to-t from-[#983BFE] to-[#D643FE] absolute transform translate-x-[90rem] translate-y-[8rem]"
    ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola ya revisaste que el zoom en la otra tab esta apropiadamente reseteado? tu proyecto no carga sale 404

Answer (score 0):

si creo que era que trabaje el sitio en 75% zoom todo el tiempo, verifique y asi estaba abriendo automaticamente desde VS-code a chrome

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).